# Comscore enable HTTPS - Android

Tags: android, https, comscore

I am using comscore-3.1508.28-v2.jar for my android application. To enable HTTPS, I have made the setSecure as true. But then also, it is hitting HTTP. I am wondered and doesn't know why. Please help me on this.

Note: To track URLS, I am using Charles.

Thanks,